# How to access the routing params from outside a component?

Tags: javascript, react-router, redux

How can I compute params from location. I'm using redux and reselect. I used to access router.params in some of my selectors. Now I have only access to routing.location.

I tried to find an helper function in react-router, but I haven't found it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router has no relation to Redux and could not have provided something like `state.router.params` to you.

You might be mistaking it with one of the community packages like [redux-router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router) which you can still use. You probably switched to [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) which is more stable but purposefully doesn’t give you access to the routing params from the state. Both libraries explain their differences in their respective READMEs so I encourage you to read both an pick the one that better fits your needs.

You don’t have to use either of those libraries though!

In general we recommend that you just **use the props you receive from the router itself in your route handler component.** Make sure it is connected, and use the second argument to `mapStateToProps` to read the route params:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const id = ownProps.params.id
  return {
    post: state.posts[id]
  }
}
```

Similarly, **you can access the props with Reselect when you define a second `props` argument on the selector itself.** The Reselect README [describes this use case](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors). Technically you’re still passing the params from your components, but your selectors can have access to them this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I missed this info from reselect's documentation.

Comment: If this helps you, do you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetely react-router is hard to work with. Personally I do following workaround:
In main route component (App) `<Route path="/" component={App} />` define two methods:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    globalModel.router.set(props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    globalModel.router.set(nextProps);
  }
```

So I have current router props in globalModel (may be flux store).